# Page content loads before Loading animation

Tags: html, css, loading

Please check this page: http://www.soumyajitnayak.com/index.html

The page content loads and then the loading animation starts. Can anyone please suggest how to make the loading animation come first before the content?

I tried async some css and js but then the page doesn't work in firefox.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you using rocket-src? You must include the script that handles the loading element/animation as soon in your head as possible.

Comment: @MohitBhardwaj: Thanks. I checked my code. I didn't add rocket-src. The browser is automatically adding that. My loading animation is in <div>. How can I add it in <head>?